# Getting soapUI to show attachment in attachments tab for a response

Tags: http, soapui

I have a REST service that returns a file through an HTTP GET.

I've set these headers in the response (on the server) and the download works perfectly in any browser:


`Content-Length

Content-Type

Content-Disposition`

However, in soapUI it simply prints the binary output to the response window-I'd like to get the file into the "Attachments" tab at the bottom.

I've tried multipart/mixed to no avail.

Anyone know how I should make the server form the response so that soapUI will put the file in the Attachments tab?

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

I don't know how to put the file in the Attachments tab but I know that you can convert the binary output in file by groovy.

You can try this script , simply fill the three variable extension,name,textBase64.

```
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64
def extension = (##extension of your file##)
def name = (##name of your file ##) 
def textBase64 =(##binary output from your request##) 


// Access element Base64-encoded text content 
String tempFilename = "${name}.${extension}"
def b64 = new Base64()
def TextBytes = b64.decode(textBase64.getBytes())

// Output text into a temporary file
def File = new java.io.File(tempFilename)
FileOutputStream fos = new java.io.FileOutputStream(File)
fos.write( TextBytes )
fos.flush()
fos.close()
log.info "File stored as: ${File.getCanonicalPath()}"
```

Better script probably exist but this one work well for me